# Проблема с подключением модуля tkinter в PyCharm Python

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, pycharm

Дублирую вопрос, поскольку ответа не нашел.

1. Linux Mint 19.3
2. Python 3.7 , установлен  в PySharm как Base Interpreter, с кучей других программ и пакетов работает без проблем.
3. PyCharm community edition 2020.1

Пытаюсь запустить через PyCharm тестовую программу с использованмем tkinter со стороками:

```
   try:
    import Tkinter as tk # this is for python2
except:
    import tkinter as tk # this is for python3

Ответ:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Что уже сделано:

**sudo apt-get install python3-tk**   прошло нормально

**python -m tkinter** окошко показывает, работает нормально

Тестовая программка на PySimpleGUI (требует tkinter) при запуске в системной  консоли работает.

В настройках **PyCharm->Progect Interpreter-> +**    модуля **tkinter** нет есть масса дополнительных к tkinter  модулей
В настройках **PyCharm->Progect Interpreter-> pip**     модуля **tkinter** нет

Попытка поставить модуль через PIP не проходит

```
pip3 install tkinter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

Вопрос: как подключить в PyCharm модуль tkinter с учетом того, что типовые методы не сработали.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter Возможное решение проблемы...

Comment: "как подключить в PyCharm" -  а причём тут PyCharm ?! Если Вы подозреваете, что при запуске скрипта в IDE PyCharm что-то не так настраивается, то запустите скрипт из командной строки: *python3 programm.py*  и сразу станет ясно, при делах здесь PyCharm, или нет.

Comment: Потому, что из командной строки прямым вызовом а PyCharm модуля нет. Я это все подробно описал.

Comment: Veter_ok, Все рекомендации из указанной статьи уже выполнены.

Answer (score 2):

Я столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой, и я обнаружил, что это проблема самого PyCharm. При запуске в терминале интерпретатора python из виртуального окружения все импорты нормально работают, но вот при запуске программы из самого PyCharm с тем же виртуальным окружением появляется ошибка. Причем, если внимательно посмотреть на сообщение об ошибке, мы увидим, что импорт происходит через некий пакет pydev_bundle внутри PyCharm, который и генерирует эту ошибку. Разобраться более детально, как этот пакет устроен, и действительно ли проблема именно в нем, я не смог.

Но вспомнив, что я установил PyCharm через Flatpak, я подумал, что проблема может быть именно в этом. Удалил PyCharm и установил заново, скачав дистрибутив с сайта разработчика. Все стало работать как надо. Я уже сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой, когда установил Sublime через тот же Flatpak - он тоже "не видел" некоторых модулей системного python. Проблема аналогично решилась, когда я установил sublime из репозитория разработчика. Почему это так - не знаю, надо разбираться с самим Flatpak, очевидно, проблема в нем.

UPD:
Как я и думал, проблема в том, что Flatpak "упаковывает" приложения в изолированное окружение, из которого им недоступны пакеты, установленные в системе. Так что PyCharm ни в чем не виноват, а вот о наличии такой проблемы стоило бы предупреждать всех, кто будет устанавливать IDE (эту или любую другую) через Flatpak.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте зайти в Settings/Project:"ProjectName"/ProjectInterepter/нажать на (+)/добавить нужный модуль.Бывало такое,что в cmd модуль вызывается и импортируется,а в pycharm-нет,вышеописанные действия исправляли проблему,в моем случае.

Comment: Kolinf,   Это сработало в многих модулях, но не tkinter

Comment: [Видео с решением данной проблемы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SvmrzqVmXo).Попробуйте посмотреть это видео,как ни странно,**просто перевыбрать файл интерпретатора (тобишь python.exe)** после установки каждого нового модуля ,решает проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, не сработало((( . Возможно, потому, что у но у меня Linux

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же ошибка и вот решение и собственно проблема:

Эта проблема из-за того что у вас какая-нибудь папка или файл.ру называется tkinter и он пытается импортировать от туда, если это так то переименуйте эти файлы и программа уже не будет путаться.